# "low level" 3D graphics programming

Tags: graphics, 3d, language-agnostic

I want to learn the fundamentals of programming 3D graphics from the bottom up. I don't necessarily want to learn DirectX or OpenGL at the moment, but to truly understand what is going on below the surface. I want to start by implementing a basic ray-tracer. It seems simple enough and there are even tutorials online for it.

After this I want to implement in software outside of DirectX or OpenGL a graphics pipeline. Is this possible or will I be trying to walk through a brick wall. They do say the best way to learn is by doing.

Comment: Brush up on your matrices first.

Comment: I do want to add that I'm not trying to become a 2nd John Carmack, but are there *MODERN* books that explain the math and the low level concepts behind a modern graphics pipeline. I know it has changed recently with the introduction of programmable pipelines using shaders.

Comment: I think the most 'modern' description would be a specification of latest DX/OGL.

Comment: If you are more interested in the math behind the scenes then a "modern" DX/OGL book is not probably what you want, since it is being the same math since a while ago. Here are two books that are great if you want to explore doing your own engine: http://www.amazon.ca/Game-Engine-Architecture-Engineering-Applications/dp/012229064X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1396274340&sr=8-1&keywords=3D+Game+Engine+Architecture and http://www.amazon.ca/Game-Engine-Design-Practical-Real-Time/dp/0122290631/ref=pd_sim_b_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=0A8TVW3BCFAWVTKJP5M6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3D graphics is a big area and to answer your question really requires a bit more information on what your goals are.

Writing a ray tracer is definitely a good way to learn some 3D graphics fundamentals. DirectX and OpenGL are of course designed to talk to hardware accelerators for rasterization based 3D rendering so if you really want to understand what's going on at the low level in the sense of how a 3D graphics card produces images of triangles on a screen then writing a software rasterizer would be a good exercise.

If your interest is more in the fundamentals of how to render a realistic image of a 3D scene however then I wouldn't necessarily advise focusing on the details of writing a rasterizer. I'd instead focus on learning more about things like lighting, shading, shadowing, reflection and refraction and global illumination. All of these things can be implemented relatively straightforwardly in a software ray-tracer, much of the complexity comes from trying to make them efficient rather than in the fundamental principles.

If your goal is more to understand how 3D hardware works at the low level, that is a whole other large topic of its own. There are good resources out there to learn about that but writing a software raytracer won't necessarily be as helpful if that is your goal.

Comment: Does DirectX and OpenGL just manage your graphics card, or does it do  some of the work for you, like transferring from different coordinate systems, etc... I want to do everything so I know how it all works.

Comment: Back in the pre-shader era of fixed function graphics APIs, DirectX and OpenGL did some of the transform and lighting work for you. Nowadays it's mostly up to you to do all of that in your vertex and pixel shaders. Nowadays OpenGL and Direct3D mostly just handle talking to the graphics card and some resource management and synchronization, plus compilation of your shader code.

Comment: So as they evolved, they "removed" features? (I know they grew more complicated as the graphics cards grew more complicated).

Comment: You could say they 'removed' features but really those features just became redundant and added clutter to the API. OpenGL hasn't actually fully removed the fixed function support, it is just deprecated. The problem with fixed function transform and lighting was that it was 'fixed' - you were stuck with a particular limited set of options for doing transform, lighting and shading which limited the variety and quality of results you could achieve. There were some attempts to make the 'fixed' pipelines more configurable but that rapidly became more complex than just writing a shader.